# Elasticsearch: Intuitive Date Search

Tags: date, search, elasticsearch, types, format

I have a dt_birth property of type date. I would like to be able to search for a date in different ways. For example 1/13/1992, 01/13/1992, 1-13-1992, January 13, 1992. How could I go about this? Currently I can only search by the format I have implemented bellow:

```
dt_birth: {
  type: 'date',
  format: 'strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis'
},
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE: I am having a few issues comprehending this.
for the dt_birth format:

```
dt_birth: {
  type: 'date',
  format: 'strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis' 
}
```

How does the format specified above 'strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis' effect the query format specified below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dt_birth": {
        "gte": "01/13/1992",
        "lte": "1-13-1992",
        "format": "d/MM/yyyy||dd/MM/yyyy||d-MM-yyyy||dd-MM-yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I'm a bit confused when you say add the date formats you need to support. How does the format correspond to the LTE and GTE? For example I would like to accept the date format January 15, 2000 - 1/15/2000 - 01/15/200 - 1-15-2000 - 01-15-2000. If I have 5 different formats I wish to support would that mean I would need 5 GTE/LTE? These last two questions are the most confusing. I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Except for the official Elastic doc page about dates and date math, is there any place **where to know exactly which standards/formats Elasticsearch is using for dates?** E.g. I can use *"tomorrow"* as expression but it is not mentioned anywhere in the whole doc, so I assume it comes from some standard format (that is not mentioned anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your `dt_birth` field contains the date format that ES expects to find in your document when you index it, so that it can retrieve the number of milliseconds (as a long) and index that.

At query time, you have the option to search by date by specifying any other date format using the `format` property of the [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_format_in_range_queries):

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dt_birth": {
        "gte": "01/13/1992",
        "lte": "1-13-1992",
        "format": "d/MM/yyyy||dd/MM/yyyy||d-MM-yyyy||dd-MM-yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dt_birth": {
        "gte": "1/13/1992",
        "lte": "January 13, 1992",
        "format": "d/MM/yyyy||MMMM dd, yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can simply add all the date formats you need to support at query time in the `format` property and then simply fill the `gte` and `lte` properties with the appropriate dates. ES will happily parse them.

Comment: I attempted implementing your answer and found that there seems to be a bit of confusion between gte/lte queries and the formats they correspond to. As a user searches for a date of birth they will only provide ONE search query .. perhaps January 13, 1992 or 1/13/1992. GTE/LTE seems to ask for MULTIPLE queries by a user. Its ES responsibility to match it to the date corresponding to that search. I have edited the question in the update section to go more into details of what I am trying to achieve. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey @val I actually got it all figured out, it works well now. Just an issue with the format on my end. The only issue I have now is attempting to do this search across _all. I'll be making a separate questions for that. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: awesome, glad you figured it out